# Empty JSON Http Response for Text

Tags: xml, rest, metamug

```
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">

<Request method="GET">
    <Desc> Example Resource </Desc>
    <Text id="msg"> Hello World </Text>
</Request>
```

I created the above resource in metamug console resource editor. I see no errors in the editor and resource xml
compiles. But when I try to access the sources I get {} empty json response.

[image: Metamug API Console Resource Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text tag by default doesn’t print its output in the response. It is designed to be used as text value store.

If you want to output Text to response, add `output="true"` attribute like you would do on other elements like Sql and Execute.

Refer official [Docs](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file#text-tag)

Cheers!

Comment: Let me try this and I’ll get back to you

Comment: I got the following response after adding output=true. `{"msg":"Hello World"}`